# How would I handle this 301 redirect in apache?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have a lot of pages that are setup like so from an old site:

```
http://www.domain.com/directory/onedirectory/whatever1
http://www.domain.com/directory/onedirectory/whatever2
http://www.domain.com/directory/onedirectory/whatever3

http://www.domain.com/directory/anotherdirectory/whatever1
http://www.domain.com/directory/anotherdirectory/whatever2
http://www.domain.com/directory/anotherdirectory/whatever3
```

Basically, I've gotten rid of all of the 'whatever' directories, so there is only one directory that has one page (and index.php), so now there is only:

```
http://www.domain.com/directory/onedirectory
http://www.domain.com/directory/anotherdirectory
```

How would I make it so that all of the 'whatever' directories, redirect back to the parent?  I'm at a loss.  I've tried many things but none have worked and they usually end up creating an infinite loop.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

-Jeremy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing you want to do here would be use [mod_redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) so for example :-

```
ReWriteRule /directory/onedirectory/whatever1 /directory/onedirectory
```

You can even extend this and use regular expressions to do inline substituions, have a peek at [this tutorial](http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/server/apache/mod-rewrite/) for some help